# Hugo Theme Not Loading

Tags: github, github-pages, hugo

I have a Hugo website that is working locally but when I deploy it to the GitHub website, the theme does not load. The website is at: `matthewcrews.com`. The repo which hosts the site is at `https://github.com/matthewcrews/matthewcrews.github.io`. The content for the website is managed at `https://github.com/matthewcrews/blog`. This setup is per the instructions on the Hugo website for setting up a page that will be hosted on GitHub. The `config.toml` is as follows:

```
baseURL = "https://matthewcrews.com"
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "My New Hugo Site"
theme = "hugo-PaperMod"
```

When I run the site locally I get what I expect:

[image]

When I guild and upload it to `https://github.com/matthewcrews/matthewcrews.github.io`, I get this:

[image]

There are no clear errors that I can find. Why is the theme not loading?

**EDIT 2020-1128 19:07 PST**

I am getting the following erro but I have no idea what it means.

Error Text:

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://matthewcrews.com/assets/css/stylesheet.min.8cbe03cd36d575ee2d4398db2c2b89694db1f7cf71d909908b0cf8aeca1ad007.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'NKDquP9+VB7hHwt5XWjGzS7hEaS/jjp7y5hsSpIBuNI='. The resource has been blocked.
```

The issue appears to be with line endings and the SHA-256 hash that is generated. The hash was likely generated on a machine where the line endings are LF. I am developing on Windows where the files have a line ending of CRLF. It appears that these are in conflict. I have to disable the integrity check to get it to work. How can I fix the integrity check?

Error image:

[image]

Comment: look at the errors ... bottom picture ... click the red X at top right

Comment: I have no idea what those errors even mean. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: yes, adding the error text is a good thing, but not a picture of the text ... also google the error text to learn what causes it

Comment: That's the thing. Google is not yielding useful results.

Comment: i got some hits at github that may apply to you ... it takes a lot longer than just a few minutes to determine usefulness of a link ... what text did you search for?

Comment: It has something to do with an integrity check but none of the suggestions have resolved the problem.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926878/failed-to-find-a-valid-digest-in-the-integrity-attribute-for-resource-in-blazo?

Comment: Did you get it working yet? I am having the same problem.