# i have faced an error on blazor webassembly when i refresh page on browser after loading first time. Sometime i faced this issue

Tags: asp.net-core

Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://localhost:90/_framework/Heir.Blazor.Manager.dll' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'f3IxbqueH8AxtH+5Q92IoxZgKnnKFzO2hJc0KDJWovE='. The resource has been blocked.
login:1 Unknown error occurred while trying to verify integrity.
blazor.webassembly.js:1 Error: Failed to start platform. Reason: TypeError: Failed to fetch
at At (blazor.webassembly.js:1:59510)

Comment: You can try to refer to what `Michel Jansson` [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926878/failed-to-find-a-valid-digest-in-the-integrity-attribute-for-resource-in-blazo).

Comment: i tried it is not working thank you