# Blazor WASM: Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource '<URL>' when visit by domain name

Tags: asp.net, .net, blazor

I have a asp.net.core hosted Blazor WASM app running on .NET 7, on Ubuntu with Nginx.

When I visite my app by IP address, the web app works just fine. But when I visite it by domain name, it fails to load and shows these errors:

`Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource '<URL>' with computed SHA-256 integrity '47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='. The resource has been blocked.`

Here is a screenshot of the errors:

[image: Picture of errors]

I can access my web api successfully by domain name.

I've found some related questions, such as [Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource in Blazor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926878/failed-to-find-a-valid-digest-in-the-integrity-attribute-for-resource-in-blazo), but in my case the app works fine when I visite it by IP.

Answer (score 1):

On the server where you deployed the application, delete all *.gz and *.br files in the application-root-folder\wwwroot_framework folder. Then access the application from a browser. This seems to be a common problem in Blazor application development. Therefore, it is expected that this method will solve the problem in other environments as well.

Comment: This is what solves the problem in a deployable way Because on a buildserver i cant delete the obj and bin folders.