# Failed to fetch and find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute

Tags: c#, blazor

Here we go. I have a website built with `NET8` and `Blazor`. At the end of the day, when all the new PRs are merged in the developer branch, there is a deployment to the hosting provider.

If I open the website, I get a lot of errors related to integrity and failed to fetch

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://mywebsite/_framework/dotnet.native.wasm' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'Vr6ZXKoP77zgabrMIxQ1GbOkrxfx5XGqHO0odLhUIMY='. The resource has been blocked.
>
> Failed to fetch

[image]

[image]

I tried to refresh the website using Ctrl+F5 but the errors are still there. What can I do?

Comment: Do you try delete bin and obj folder? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75347986/20240963