blazor webassembly error: cannot read properties if undefined (reading 'dotnet.wasm')
The question is obvious: how to fix the cited error message from the title. In the first part I show a picture of the generated error message and I explain the undertaken steps to provoke said error message.

I've some problems deploying a blazor wasm app to a server on a website subdomain.
As that didn't work out, I thaught, let's go step by step, and try to deploy the microsoft sample (the counter application) to the subdomain.
That initially worked out and I tried consequently to deploy a more complicated application to the subdomain.
That still didn't work out, and I placed the counter application back. Just to check. Being unpleasantly surprised to have this message when I ran the application locally.


I than consulted following SO-topic
It is true that when trying and erring with deployments I added and removed .Net sdk's (bundles)
I ran the most recent .Net bundle again. And restarted IIS.

No change.
I looked at the application and although the application was targetting .net 8, and was up to date on 8.0.4, the packages Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer were still on 8.0.2 so I upgraded them to 8.0.4.

I also checked the targeted framework.

Removed bin- and obj-folders, and republished again. And deployed again. But the error message remained.

Did you try to run the website from another computer (not on the server you deployed on) and what did the error message say?

It gave me a "Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource" in Blazor app. I see there's a topic on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926878/failed-to-find-a-valid-digest-in-the-integrity-attribute-for-resource-in-blazo.

The error I got when trying to reach the website from a remote computer was:

As mentioned in the linked topic, don't also forget to empty the cache of the browser (ctrl + f5).
So the answer is two fold. Do the things with the packages, as described above, and then don't forget to refresh the browser.
